# Split XML to Multiple Htmls using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a huge XML file and there is "entryHeaderHeader" tag which repeats about more than 9000 rows. I just wanted to split 9 html documents (split by 1000 rows)

I tried to use xsl:result-document and mod operations but failed.
Thank you for your helps

All lines of XSL File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
    xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2006-10-25" 
    xmlns:gl-cor="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25" 
    xmlns:gl-gen="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/gen/2006-10-25" 
    xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" 
    xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" 
    xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" 
    xmlns:xl="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:edefter="http://www.edefter.gov.tr">

    <xsl:output version="4.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="tryFormat" grouping-separator="." decimal-separator=","/>
    <xsl:variable name="VKN" select="/edefter:defter/xbrli:xbrl[1]/xbrli:context[1]/xbrli:entity[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="UNVAN" select="/edefter:defter/xbrli:xbrl[1]/gl-cor:accountingEntries[1]/gl-cor:entityInformation/gl-bus:organizationIdentifiers[gl-bus:organizationDescription = 'Kurum Unvanı' ]/gl-bus:organizationIdentifier" />
    <xsl:variable name="SUBE_ADI" select="/edefter:defter/xbrli:xbrl[1]/gl-cor:accountingEntries[1]/gl-cor:entityInformation/gl-bus:organizationIdentifiers[gl-bus:organizationDescription = 'Şube Adı' ]/gl-bus:organizationIdentifier" />

    <!-- Donusturme islemi baslnagic yeri. edefter:defter -->
    <xsl:template match="/edefter:defter">

        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body.bodyClass{
                        font-family:Arial Narrow; 
                        font-size:10pt; 
                    }

                    table.pageHeader1{
                        border:0; 
                        cellpadding:2;
                        cellspacing:5;
                        width:100%;
                        font-weight:bold; 
                    }

                    table.pageHeader2{
                        border:0; 
                        width:100%;
                        border-spacing: 6px;
                    }

                    table.pageHeader2 tbody tr{
                        border-bottom-style:none; 
                    }

                    table.pageHeader2 tbody tr:nth-child(1) td{
                        border-bottom-color:black; 
                        border-bottom-style:dashed; 
                        border-bottom-width:thin; 
                        overflow:inherit; 
                        padding-bottom:2px; 
                        text-align:center; 
                        font-weight:bold; 
                    }

                    table.pageHeader2 tbody tr:nth-child(2) td{
                        border-top-color:black; 
                        border-top-style:dashed; 
                        border-top-width:thin; 
                        overflow:inherit;
                    }

                    table.entryHeaderHeader {
                        width:100%; 
                        font-weight:bold;
                        margin-bottom:20px;
                    }

                    table.entryHeaderHeader tr td:nth-child(1){
                        width:40%; 
                        padding-left:5px;
                    }

                    table.entryHeaderHeader tr td:nth-child(2){
                        width:45%; 
                        padding-left:5px;
                    }

                    table.entryHeaderHeader tr td:nth-child(3){
                        width:300px;
                    }                                   

                    table.entryHeaderHeader tr td div:nth-child(2){
                        border-bottom-style:dashed; 
                        border-bottom-width:2px; 
                        border-color:black; 
                        font-size:1px; 
                        margin-top:-8px; 
                        margin-left:80px; 
                        margin-right:10px;
                    }

                    table.entryDetail{
                        border:0; 
                        overflow:hidden; 
                        width:100%; 
                        margin-top:5px;  
                        cellpadding:0; 
                        cellspacing:2;
                    }

                    table.entryDetail tr{
                        height:0.2in;
                    }

                    div.entryHeaderFooter{
                        margin-bottom:15px; 
                        text-align:center; 
                    }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body class="bodyClass">

                <xsl:apply-templates select="xbrli:xbrl" />

            </body>
        </html> 


    </xsl:template>

    <!-- xbrli:xbrl -->
    <xsl:template match="xbrli:xbrl">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gl-cor:accountingEntries"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- gl-cor:accountingEntries -->
    <xsl:template match="gl-cor:accountingEntries">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gl-cor:entityInformation"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gl-cor:documentInfo"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="printPageHeader"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gl-cor:entryHeader"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="printPageFooter"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- gl-cor:entityInformation -->
    <xsl:template match="gl-cor:entityInformation">
        <table style="width:100%; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; margin-top:40px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left; padding-bottom:20px;">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Kurum Unvanı : </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$UNVAN"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:right; font-size:16px;">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>YEVMİYE DEFTERİ</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left; padding-bottom:20px;">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Şube Adı: </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$SUBE_ADI"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left; padding-top:10px;">                             
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Vergi No: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$VKN"/>
                        </span>                             
                    </td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- gl-cor:documentInfo -->
    <xsl:template match="gl-cor:documentInfo">
        <table style="width:100%; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:30px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px;">                               
                        <span>
                            <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:entriesComment"/>
                        </span>                             
                    </td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- printPageHeader -->
    <xsl:template name="printPageHeader">
        <table class="pageHeader1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:40%;">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Yevmiye Madde No</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:40%;">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Yevmiye Tarihi</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:300px; "/>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
        <table class="pageHeader2" >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:155px;">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Hesap Kodu</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:2.28in;">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Hesap Adı</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                        <br/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:2.97in;">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Açıklama</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:70px; ">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Borç </xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:65px; ">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>Alacak</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:155px; ">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:2.28in; ">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:2.97in; ">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:70px; ">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:65px; ">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- printPageFooter -->
    <xsl:template name="printPageFooter">
        <hr width="100%" style="border: 1px dashed black;" color="#FFFFFF" size="6"/>
        <table style="border:0; font-style:normal; width:100%; margin-bottom:50px; " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="font-style:normal; height:0.01in; ">
                    <td style="width:50in; "/>
                    <td style="text-align:right; width:10in; ">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; ">
                            <xsl:text>Borç Toplamı :</xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:11in; "/>
                    <td style="text-align:right; width:5in; ">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; ">
                            <xsl:variable name="debitSum">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(sum(gl-cor:entryHeader/gl-bus:totalCredit)), '###.##0,00', 'tryFormat')"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$debitSum"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:5in; "/>
                </tr>
                <tr style="font-style:normal; height:0.01in; ">
                    <td style="width:50in;"/>
                    <td style="width:10in;"/>
                    <td style="text-align:right; width:11in; ">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; ">
                            <xsl:text>Alacak Toplamı : </xsl:text>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:5in; "/>
                    <td style="text-align:right; width:5in; ">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; ">
                            <xsl:variable name="creditSum">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(sum(gl-cor:entryHeader/gl-bus:totalDebit)), '###.##0,00', 'tryFormat')"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$creditSum"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- gl-cor:entryHeader -->
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <xsl:template match="gl-cor:entryHeader">

            <xsl:call-template name="printEntryHeaderHeader"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="gl-cor:entryDetail"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="printEntryHeaderFooter"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- printEntryHeaderHeader -->
    <xsl:template name="printEntryHeaderHeader">

        <table class="entryHeaderHeader">
            <xsl:result-document href="yevmiye{position()}.html" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <xsl:text>[ </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:entryNumberCounter"/>
                        <xsl:text> ]</xsl:text> 
                    </div>
                    <div/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <xsl:text>[ </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:call-template name="convertDate">
                            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="gl-cor:enteredDate"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:text> ]</xsl:text>                     
                    </div>  
                    <div/>
                </td>
                <td/>
            </tr>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </table>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- gl-cor:entryDetail -->
    <xsl:template match="gl-cor:entryDetail">

        <xsl:variable name="debitCreditNote" select="normalize-space(gl-cor:debitCreditCode)" />
        <xsl:variable name="amount" select="format-number(number(gl-cor:amount), '###.##0,00', 'tryFormat')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="documentType" select="normalize-space(gl-cor:documentType)"/>

        <table class="entryDetail">         
            <!-- print main acoount information -->
            <tr>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$debitCreditNote = 'C' or $debitCreditNote = 'credit'">
                        <td style="width:30px;"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>                   
                <td style="width:150px; font-weight:bold; padding-left:10px;">
                    <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:account/gl-cor:accountMainID"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>                     
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">
                    <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:account/gl-cor:accountMainDescription"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>                        
                </td>
                <td style="width:100px; text-align:right; padding-right:20px;" >
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$debitCreditNote = 'D' or $debitCreditNote = 'debit'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$amount"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>                       
                </td>
                <td style="width:100px; text-align:right; padding-right:20px;" >
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$debitCreditNote = 'C' or $debitCreditNote = 'credit'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$amount"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>                   
            </tr>
            <!-- print sub account information -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="gl-cor:account/gl-cor:accountSub/gl-cor:accountSubID">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$debitCreditNote = 'C' or $debitCreditNote = 'credit'">
                                <td style="width:30px;"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>                   
                        <td style="width:150px; padding-left:10px;">
                            <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:account/gl-cor:accountSub/gl-cor:accountSubID"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>                        
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:account/gl-cor:accountSub/gl-cor:accountSubDescription"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>                       
                        </td>               
                    </tr>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <!-- print payment method -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space(gl-bus:paymentMethod)) != 0 ">
                    <tr style="font-size:8pt; font-style:italic;">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$debitCreditNote = 'C' or $debitCreditNote = 'credit'">
                                <td style="width:30px;"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>                   
                        <td style="width:150px;"/>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-weight:bold;">Ödeme Şekli : </span><xsl:value-of select="gl-bus:paymentMethod"/>                  
                        </td>               
                    </tr>                       
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <!-- print document type, document number, document date -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($documentType) != 0" >
                    <xsl:variable name="documentNumber" select="normalize-space(gl-cor:documentNumber)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="documentDate" select="normalize-space(gl-cor:documentDate)"/>
                    <tr style="font-size:8pt; font-style:italic;">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$debitCreditNote = 'C' or $debitCreditNote = 'credit'">
                                <td style="width:30px;"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>                   
                        <td style="width:150px;"/>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:variable name="documentName">
                                <xsl:call-template name="findDocumentType">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="entryDetail" select="."/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:variable>                             
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="string-length($documentNumber) > 0 or string-length($documentDate) > 0">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="string-length($documentNumber) > 0 ">
                                            <span style="font-weight:bold;"><xsl:value-of select="$documentName"/> No : </span><xsl:value-of select="$documentNumber"/>
                                            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>                                         
                                        </xsl:when>                                     
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="string-length($documentDate) > 0 ">
                                            <span style="font-weight:bold;"><xsl:value-of select="$documentName"/> Tarihi : </span>
                                            <xsl:call-template name="convertDate">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$documentDate"/>
                                            </xsl:call-template>                                            
                                        </xsl:when> 
                                    </xsl:choose>                                   
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <span style="font-weight:bold;">Belge Türü : </span><xsl:value-of select="$documentName"/>  
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>       
                        </td>               
                    </tr>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>           
        </table>    
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- printEntryHeaderFooter  -->
    <xsl:template name="printEntryHeaderFooter">
        <div class="entryHeaderFooter">
            <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:entryComment"/>
            <br/> 
            <xsl:text>Muhasebe Fiş No : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:entryNumber"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="convertDate">
        <xsl:param name="date"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($date,9,2),'/', substring($date, 6,2), '/', substring($date,1,4))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="findDocumentType">
        <xsl:param name="entryDetail"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$entryDetail/gl-cor:documentType = 'check'">
                <xsl:text>Çek </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$entryDetail/gl-cor:documentType = 'invoice'">
                <xsl:text>Fatura</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$entryDetail/gl-cor:documentType = 'order-customer'">
                <xsl:text>Müşteri Siparişi</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$entryDetail/gl-cor:documentType = 'order-vendor'">
                <xsl:text>Satıcı Siparişi</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$entryDetail/gl-cor:documentType = 'voucher'">
                <xsl:text>Senet</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$entryDetail/gl-cor:documentType = 'shipment'">
                <xsl:text>Navlun</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$entryDetail/gl-cor:documentType = 'receipt'">
                <xsl:text>Makbuz</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$entryDetail/gl-cor:documentTypeDescription"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below xsl code was taken from above XSL which I want to split

```
<!-- printEntryHeaderHeader -->
<xsl:template name="printEntryHeaderHeader">

    <table class="entryHeaderHeader">
        <xsl:result-document href="yevmiye{position()}.html" >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <xsl:text>[ </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="gl-cor:entryNumberCounter"/>
                    <xsl:text> ]</xsl:text> 
                </div>
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <xsl:text>[ </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:call-template name="convertDate">
                        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="gl-cor:enteredDate"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:text> ]</xsl:text>                     
                </div>  
                <div/>
            </td>
            <td/>
        </tr>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </table>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what "I tried to use xsl:result-document and mod operations but failed" means, which exact error messages, if any, you get.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach would be to use positional grouping and `result-document` e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//entryHeaderHeader" group-adjacent="position() idiv 1000">
  <xsl:result-document href="chunk{position()}.html">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: dear Martin, your response seems which i was looking for, i will try tonight and inform, thank you